# Is void a data type in C?

Tags: c, types, void

Is `void` a data type in the C programming language? If so, what type of values can it store? If we have `int`, `float`, `char`, etc., to store values, why is `void` needed? And what is the range of void?

Comment: It fills no purpose at all, wasn't even part of the original K&R pre-ansi C.  Some idiot thought `myFunction() { /* ... */ }` looked way too neat, and just had to add some BS `void myFunction(void) { /* ... */ }` - I'd argue that there's other cleaner options in case you can't stand using `char *`, which was the common way to declare "universal" pointers before void.

Comment: @ChristofferBubach but `function(void)` != `function()` in C, because in the former you can put exactly no parameters, while in the latter you can put anything: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-int-main-int-mainvoid (except in C++, on which both mean the function takes exactly no parameters)

Comment: I have to think any c compiler would be able to quite easily detect parameter usage or external linkage in order to use the most efficient call entry points. A reverse syntax to clearly indicate unknown amount of params with ”…” or a new varargs type would be much cleaner and still allow for automatic detection when declared with just empty brackets. which is basically how new code looks anyway, so why add void as well, are compilers really this shitty at book keeping symbols and their usage?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Void is considered a data type (for organizational purposes), but it is basically a keyword to use as a placeholder where you would put a data type, to represent "no data".

Hence, you can declare a routine which does not return a value as:

```
void MyRoutine();
```

But, you cannot declare a variable like this:

```
void bad_variable;
```

However, when used as a pointer, then it has a different meaning:

```
void* vague_pointer;
```

This declares a pointer, but without specifying which data type it is pointing to.

Comment: and since you don't specify what a void pointer points to, you can't perform math on it. The compiler wouldn't know how far to move the pointer to get to the next item in memory.

Comment: `void MyRoutine();` is an old-style (K&R C) function declaration deprecated by C99, not a prototype. This should be `void MyRoutine(void);` instead.

Comment: @fennec: You can perform arithmetic on `void*` values if you're using gcc, which supports it as an extension by pretending `sizeof (void) == 1`. (I personally consider this unfortunate.)

Comment: Er... Strictly speaking, the only context in which `void` acts as a "placeholder keyword" is `(void)` function parameter list declaration. (Despite the fact that we have a type between the `()`, the function still accepts zero parameters.) In all other contexts `void` acts as a genuine *incomplete* data type, e.g. type declaration `struct foo;` will produce a type with the same properties as `void`. For this reason it is not correct to say that `void` is "not a real type" and "just a placeholder keyword". `void` is a "real" type. It just happens to be incomplete.

Comment: Thank you sir, I've been wondering why my POSIX pthread_create had as last argument a "void *" parameter... It's sort of abstraction isn't it? Like abstract data type in Java, I know it is a pointer but roughly it's same idea isn't it? You accept data but not specifying the EXACT type you can pass. So you parse it into void * and then inside the function you cast it back from void * to whatever you've been using before passing it.

Comment: The following definition works without problems: `extern void foo;`

Comment: @AnT: An imcomplete struct type doesn't have *all* the same properties as `void`. They're both incomplete types, but for example all pointer-to-struct types have the same representation; `void*` may or may not have the same representation. Also, an incomplete struct type can be completed; `void` cannot.

Comment: @Keith Thompson,  @AnT, also, a function can be declared as returning void, but not an incomplete type.  So, it may be more accurate to say, instead of "`void` is an incomplete type', rather, "incomplete types are a specialized kind of `void`"

Comment: And also keep in mind that void also has memory allocation.Sizeof(void)=1 It uses 1 byte memory.

Comment: What about `extern void x;`?

Comment: @KeithThompson What about `extern void x;`?

Comment: @UjjwalAryal No, `sizeof (void)` is a constraint violation. A gcc non-standard extension permits pointer arithmetic on `void*`, and it's implemented by *pretending* that `sizeof (void) == 1`. The extension is disabled in standard mode, e.g., `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors`.

Comment: @pmor `extern void x;` appears to be legal; both gcc and clang accept it in conforming mode -- which surprised me. It's legal to declare an `extern` object with an incomplete type, for example `extern int arr[];`; the definition must provide a complete type. I suppose `extern void x;` means it's impossible to complete the type. As far as I can tell, it's legal but useless.

Comment: @JamesCurran I must have missed your comment back in 2015. No, there's no rule that says a function cannot be declared as returning an incomplete type. A function cannot return an array or function type. I don't think it would be useful to say that "incomplete types are a specialized kind of `void`".

Comment: @KeithThompson The core question: are you absolutely sure that it is "useless"? Is there _any_ valid operation on `x` declared as `extern void x;`?

Comment: @pmor No, I'm not absolutely sure; that's why I wrote "As far as I can tell ...". I can't think of any use for it. If you can, feel free to share.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, indeed. As far as I see, `(void)x;` is a valid operation (despite of being useless).

Comment: @KeithThompson `1 ? x : x;` (and similar: e.g. `v ? f1() : x;`) is valid as well. Though some C compilers ICE on it.

Comment: @pmor A long time I used  `#define DebugPrint true ?((void)(NULL)) :printf`   That allowed me (in release builds) to write `DebugPrint("%s %d", var1,var2);` and it wouldn't generate any code.  (On debug builds, it would use a real function `DebugPrint(char*,...)` )

Comment: @JamesCurran It seems that there is a need for `(void)printf`.

Comment: @KeithThompson FYI: for `extern const void x; const void* p = &x;` both GCC and Clang produce no diagnostics.

Comment: @KeithThompson Re: "no diagnostics": this is because an expression that designates an object of type `<type-qualifier> void` (e.g. `const void`) is lvalue. Also: people [use `extern void`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27263344/1778275).

Comment: @pmor The standard says that an lvalue potentially designates an object "with an object type other than **`void`**), but I doubt that the intent was to allow an lvalue of type `const void`.

Comment: @KeithThompson I doubt too (e.g. "what is the purpose of lvalues of incomplete object type that cannot be completed?"). However, this is what C11 (as well as C2x) prescribes: "The qualified or unqualified versions of a type are _distinct types_ ...". Example: we can take an address of object of incomplete type `const void`, but we cannot complete such type. Then what is the purpose of allowing to take an address of an object of such type in the first place?...

Answer (score 36):

Yes, `void` is a type. Whether it's a *data* type depends on how you define that term; the C standard doesn't.

The standard does define the term "object type". In C99 and earlier; `void` is not an object type; in C11, it is. In all versions of the standard, `void` is an *incomplete type*. What changed in C11 is that incomplete types are now a subset of object types; this is just a change in terminology. (The other kind of type is a *function type*.)

C99 6.2.6 paragraph 19 says:

> The **void** type comprises an empty set of values; it is an incomplete
>   type that cannot be completed.

The C11 standard changes the wording slightly:

> The **void** type comprises an empty set of values; it is an incomplete object type that
>   cannot be completed.

This reflects C11's change in the definition of "object type" to include incomplete types; it doesn't really change anything about the nature of type `void`.

The `void` keyword can also be used in some other contexts:

- As the only parameter type in a function prototype, as in `int func(void)`, it indicates that the function has no parameters. (C++ uses empty parentheses for this, but they mean something else in C.)
- As the return type of a function, as in `void func(int n)`, it indicates that the function returns no result.
- `void*` is a pointer type that doesn't specify what it points to.

In principle, all of these uses refer to the *type* `void`, but you can also think of them as just special syntax that happens to use the same keyword.

Comment: what is the difference between int func() and int void()

Comment: @funky-nd: Looking at this againk I suspect you meant to ask the difference between `int func()` and `int func(void)`. The difference is that the latter is a *prototype*, which specifies that the function takes no arguments. The former is an old-style function declaration, which does not specify what arguments it expects. (There is rarely, if ever, a good reason to use old-style function declarations.)

Answer (score 8):

The C Standard says that `void` is an incomplete type that cannot be completed (unlike other incomplete types that can be completed). This means you cannot apply the `sizeof` operator to `void`, but you can have a pointer to an incomplete type.

Comment: Сonsider `extern void x;`. 1) if `x` can be completed "outside of C" (e.g. in asm), then why `&x` is invalid? 2) Is there a valid operation on `x`?

Comment: @pmor If completion happens "outside of C" that means the compiler is unaware of it. Not `&x` is invalid, `void x` is and everything that follows. As for 2), there should be, e.g. assignment of two `void x` to `void y`, but it can't be since the compiler does not know the size of x and y.

Comment: I meant "`&x` is invalid _in this case_ (i.e. if `x` is declared as `extern void x;`)".

Comment: Both Clang and GCC accept `extern const void x; const void* p = &x;` under `-std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra`. Is this code valid? If no, they why Clang and GCC decided to accept it?

Comment: @pmor Yes, this code is valid. An expression that designates an object of type `<type-qualifier> void` (e.g. `const void`) is lvalue.