# What can a void variable be used for?

Tags: java, c++, c, variables, void

For example, if I made the variable:

```
void helloWorld;
```

What could I do with it? Since it represents nothing, at first I thought that nothing could be done with it.
I am aware that functions use void for no return value, but do the variables have a purpose?

-- EDIT --

I have found out the answer. I am now aware that void variables are illegal in programming languages such as Java, C++ and C. Thanks for all of your answers!

Comment: That will cause a compilation error in `java`. Unless you meant `Void`.

Comment: Speaking strictly about Java, `void` is a keyword that's not usable with variables. Still, `Void` is the uninstantiable object supporting the `void` keyword and, since it's an object, it could actually be usable as a type.

Comment: I'm fairly sure you can't define a `void` variable in any of the three languages you're asking about; which makes the question rather pointless.

Comment: You are right that it doesn't make sense which is why you can't do that.

Comment: _void *_ are mostly used as arguments in function prototypes where that argument is designed to accept a pointer to any other type of variable.

Comment: I wonder that OP is only 14 years old! Your question deserves for +1.

Comment: @ryyker Yes, but the OP didn't ask about `void*`, he asked about `void`.

Answer (score 11):

`void` variables are invalid in C/C++ because the compiler can not determine their size. `void` is only valid as function argument list (takes no arguments) or return types (returns nothing).

There is `void *` which just means "any type pointer" and is a generic pointer type, but you are not allowed to dereference it.

Comment: Formally, the reason they are invalid is that `void` is an *incomplete type*.

Comment: @R..; Yes you are right. This is because of incomplete type (C99 6.2.6 paragraph 19)

Answer (score 6):

C99 6.2.6 paragraph 19 says:

> The **void** type comprises an empty set of values; it is an incomplete
>   type that cannot be completed.

Also, `void` in C, is a type that has no size. Thus, if you were to declare a variable of type `void`, the compiler would not know how much memory to allocate for it.
So, [**you can't declare a `void` variable**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3487716/2455888) because it is of incomplete type.

`void` is useful just when we're talking about pointers (`void*`) since it allows you to declare a generic pointer without specifying the type.

Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14060799/2455888) given by [Keith Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/827263/keith-thompson) for more detailed explanation.

Comment: So it is _possible_ (but useless) to declare a `void helloWorld` variable in C?  A reference to the standards document which you apparently used would be nice.

Comment: That answer does not declare a void variable: it evaluates a non-void variable expression and casts it to void.  I just tried to get `gcc` to accept a variable declaration `void helloWorld` (as opposed to the expression `(void) helloWorld` where `helloWorld` is declared as a non-`void`), and failed.

Comment: @MarnixKlooster; I read this in this [tutorial](http://www.crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/void.html).

Comment: @MarnixKlooster; Sorry! I misunderstood. Although it is syntactically correct, it is useless and that's why you are getting error (code will not compile).

Comment: @MarnixKlooster It is invalid because 1) void is an incomplete type (C99 6.2.5§19) and 2) an identifier declared with no linkage must have a complete type (C99 6.7§7). On the other hand, you can have a (completely useless) declaration such as `extern void x;`

Comment: @Virgile: `extern void x;` does have potential (non-portable) uses: `&x` can be useful for taking the address of asm labels in inline assembly or external asm files. This in turn can be useful for determining, from a signal handler, whether the saved program counter is between two particular asm labels.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE "The operand of the unary & operator shall be either ... or an **lvalue** that designates an object" and "An **lvalue** is an expression (with an object type **other than void**) that potentially designates an object".

Answer (score 3):

In Java, you cannot use `void` as a variable type.

You can however use [`Void`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html)

> The Void class is an uninstantiable placeholder class to hold a
>   reference to the Class object representing the Java keyword void.

You won't be able to do anything with it, except get the `Class` object, but that is a `static` field anyway so you don't need an object reference.

Answer (score 1):

In C you can cast function parameters to void

```
(void)myarg;
```

this is only useful for dealing with unused parameter warnings however.

Answer (score 0):

i think you don't know what 'void' is??? do you..

small and quick info about void

void is not a data-type like int or char that you use to declare variables.

void is a return-type

void return type is used to say that we are returning nothing from this function.

if you don't return anything then you have to write void as return-type for a function (including main function). alternatively you can say ....

```
return 0;
```

at the end of function's definition.

i hope this might helped you to understand what is void.

Comment: this is the same case with any programming language (c,c++,java,c#, vb.net, js, motif, scripting languages, pascal, cobal)... almost everywhere

Comment: I know what the void type is, I'm just asking if it can be used in a variable. I've pretty much got the answer now, so thanks for your answer. I will announce that I have gotten my answer in the above post....