# Converting the output of a void method to String in C

Tags: c, string, int

I have written a void function which takes an unsigned int. Then I call this in the main function. I want the output to be a string so that I can include it in the `printf` statement for formatting reasons. But since I'm calling a void function, I can't tell `printf` that its a string `(%s)` or an int `(%d)`. How can I take the output from this called void function in my main and turn it to some kind of string or integer?

Comment: Show the function declaration. If it is as you say, `void fn(....)`, then you can't do what you're trying. `void` means no return value.

Comment: `void something (unsigned int x){}` which returns nothing. Then in my `main`, I call `something(some value)`.

Comment: `void` means that you're not returning any data http://stackoverflow.com/a/3487716/2265932

Comment: We'll I understand that a void function returns nothing. I was just wondering if there was another way around it so that I can keep the void function but somehow convert its output to a string or an integer in the main. Is that possible?

Comment: @user3754974 What do you mean by "its output"? Something it's calculating? It's `printf` output?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart The void function does have an output which are numbers. But I want to include the output of numbers from the void function to be a string or int. Does this make sense?

Comment: Not really. You should read much more about C programming. You look very confused.

Comment: @user3754974 The "output" of a function is its return value. See my example answer.

Answer (score 2):

A function declared as e.g. `void foo(int);` has no result. So you cannot convert its inexistent result to an integer or to a string.

<sup>notice that *C* does not have stricto sensu a *string* datatype. You use pointer to memory zones made of `char`, with the convention to zero-terminate strings.</sup>

Perhaps you want to get the *output* (done using `printf`, `fprintf`, `fputs`, and other [stdio(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html) standard library functions)  of a function as a string. On Linux (and GNU libc) systems, you could use [open_memstream(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/open_memstream.3.html)

<sup>Do not confuse the output of a function with its result!</sup>

So suppose you have written some outputing function like e.g.

```
void show_x(FILE*out, int x) { fprintf(out, "x=%d\n", x); }
```

Then you could get that into a string like `ptrbuf` (on Linux) using:

```
char*ptrbuf=NULL;
size_t sizbuf=0;
FILE* outmem = open_memstream(&ptrbuf, &sizbuf);
if (!outmem) { perror("open_memstream"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
show_x(outmem, 42);
fflush(outmem);
printf ("now ptrbuf is %s\n", ptrbuf);
fclose(outmem);
// you later should free the `malloc`-ed `ptrbuf`
free (ptrbuf), ptrbuf=NULL;
sizbuf=0;
```

Comment: Considering the OP's obvious n00bish-ness, `open_memstream` seems a bit heavy here.

Comment: I would hardly think I'm a noob. Perhaps a beginner as you were at one point. But I agree, this seems a bit hardcore for me. Maybe I don't understand it yet.

Comment: Sorry if you took offense to that, "beginner" was all I really meant. We were all noobs at one point :-)

Answer (score 1):

A `void` function returns nothing. Change its return type to be `const char*` to return a C-string:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char* func_that_returns_string(unsigned int x)
{
    switch (x) {
    case 0:  return "zero";
    case 1:  return "one";
    default: return "who needs any other numbers?";
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = 3;
    const char* str;

    str = func_that_returns_string(i);

    printf("%d: %s\n", i, str);

    return 0;
}
```