# Difference between (void)obj and void(obj)

Tags: c++, casting, void

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast, C-style cast and functional cast are equivalent. However, see the following example:

```
#include <array>
int main() {
  std::array<int, 3> arr{};
  (void)arr;
  //void(arr);
}
```

While (void)arr compiles, void(arr) does not. What have I missed?

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: `void(arr)` will be parsed as a function call surely. What do you think casting to `void` even means? Because it means nothing!

Comment: Casting to `void` is valid, and it means the result of the expression is discarded. It's often used to silence unused variable warnings, and it has a use in TMP to prevent overload resolution selecting overloaded comma operators.

Comment: Valid alternative syntaxes for an expression statement casting to void include: `( void(arr) );` and `static_cast<void>(arr);`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: No, it will be parsed as a variable declaration, giving errors because a variable can't have type `void`, and there's already a variable called `arr`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour How does the compiler tell the difference between that and a function call?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: `void` can't be the name of a function, so `void(arr)` can't be a function call. (Even if it could, the Most Vexing Parse would resolve the ambiguity by interpreting it as a declaration if possible).

Comment: @MikeSeymour So, if I had a type named `x`, and a function named `x`, then `x(y);` would be a declaration?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: No, it seems that that particular ambiguity gives an error rather than arbitrarily being interpreted as a declaration. Sorry for misleading you.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Name lookup will determine whether `x` in that context refers to the type or the function and the rest of the expression will be evaluated accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there are no ambiguities (e.g. other functions with the same name, macros..) involved, [the following code](http://ideone.com/0dwDPm) declares and defines two `int` variables

```
int a = 22;
int (b) = 33;
```

thus **you're trying to create a void variable type (with an existing name)**.

And that's wrong because:

1. [You're trying to create a void variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3487716/1938163)
2. You're trying to use an existing name for another variable in the same scope

Comment: I guess I will stick to the syntax `(type)(var)` from now on to avoid this ambiguity. C++ style casts are unambiguous, but on the other hand way too nasty.

Answer (score 4):

While `void(arr)` is usually the same as `(void)arr`, in this context it is a definition, and you are trying to create a variable called `arr` of type `void`, which isn't allowed.

Comment: So short, so plausible, so actually answering the question.