# How to assert two types are equal in c?

Tags: c, types, assert

How do I assert that two types are equal in C? In C++, I would use std::is_same, but searching StackOverflow and elsewhere seems only to give results for C++ and C#. Is there no way to do this in C?

---

Note, this is not asking whether a variable has a certain type but rather whether two types are the same.

Comment: Given that there's no `decltype` in C, you'd be stuck comparing typedefs or using `typeof` extensions even if you had a way to do this test.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a variable is of a certain type (compare two types) in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280055/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-is-of-a-certain-type-compare-two-types-in-c)

Comment: @ShadowRanger: That's testing a variable against a type, not testing two types against each other.

Comment: So this is not part of standard C, I take it? What is the barrier to implementing such a functionality, especially when types are known at compile time? Or is it just a question of "philosophy" in C versus C++?

Comment: In what form are the types available? If we can put them into type declarations, then something like `typedef T0; typedef T1;` may complain if and only if the types are different. (Testing shows it complains even if the types are compatible, such as an incomplete array and a complete array, but I need to check the C standard further.) But this requires they be in a declarable form with the same identifier, such as `int x[3]`. If we just have `int [3]`, preprocessor expansion cannot form `int x[3]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How to assert two types are equal in c?

Use `_Generic` to get you at least mostly there with non-array types.

```
#define compare_types(T1, T2) _Generic((  (T1){0}  ), \
  T2: "Same", \
  default: "Different" \
)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
  // Same range
  printf("%ld %lld\n", LONG_MAX, LLONG_MAX);
  // Same size
  printf("%zu %zu\n", sizeof (long), sizeof (long long));
  // Yet different
  printf("%s\n", compare_types(long, long long));

  // int64_t is a long on my machine
  printf("%s\n", compare_types(long, int64_t));
  printf("%s\n", compare_types(long long, int64_t));
}
```

Output

```
9223372036854775807 9223372036854775807
8 8
Different
Same
Different
```

---

**Improved**

Further, a stronger compare employs a `A vs B` and  `B vs A` test.   The 2 tests are useful for the controlling expression of `_Generic` converts arrays to pointers of the first element losing some type information.

```
#define strong_helper(T1, T2) _Generic(( (T1){0} ), \
  T2: 1, \
  default: 0 \
)
#define compare_types_strong(T1, T2) (strong_helper(T1,T2) && strong_helper(T2,T1))

printf("%d\n", compare_types_strong(long, int64_t));
printf("%d\n", compare_types_strong(int [3], int *));
```

Output

```
1
0
```

---

**Still troublesome for arrays and `void`**

`compare_types_strong(int [3], int [3])` returns 0 as `_Generic` converted the controlling expression `int [3]` to a pointer to the first element type (`int *`).

[@PSkocik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53840498/how-to-assert-two-types-are-equal-in-c/53841007?noredirect=1#comment94534472_53841007), in a deleted comment, points out this approach will not work for the [*incomplete object type* `void`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14060799/2410359).

Comment: @EricPostpischil My `compare_types(int *, int [3])` reports `"Different"` (gcc version 7.3.0 ).  What compiler/version are you using?

Comment: Oops, my mistake. `int *, int [3]` reports “Different”. `int [3], int *` gets a compilation error. Apple LLVM 9.1.0, clang-902.0.39.2.

Comment: @PSkocik As standard C does not have `__typeof` nor `typeof`, using that would make for a compiler specific solution  OK if OP wants that, but so far post is not tagged as such.

Comment: I use GCC for compliation and Clang/LLVM for static analysis, so a compiler-specific solution would be fine, although a standard-based solution is of course preferred.

Comment: @ZachBoyd In the end, I suspect that either 1) a standard based solution as above that does not work well  for array and `void` or 2) a compiler-specific solution is the answer.  In any case, the question implies no compiler-specific solution allowance.  Perhaps explaining _why_ this this ability is needed and how it is used will result in an even better solution that is universal and portable.

Comment: Part of the question is just curiosity, but the specific motivating case I was looking at was for a library I rely on where a "real number" type is just floating point double but is not guaranteed to stay that way and/or may be configurable. I wanted to put a check in my code that uses the assumption that the real number type is exactly double to call attention in case of future changes. So in this case, the array case is not needed, although it is of interest in general.

Comment: @ZachBoyd Thanks for that detail.  It is a prudent use of something like `_Static_assert(compare_types_strong(double, lib_FP), "Unexpected lib_FP");`

Answer (score 3):

Under gcc, you could do something like this:

```
#define same_type(a, b) \ 
    static_assert(__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(a), typeof(b)), "types do not match")

...

int a, b;
float c;
same_type(a,b);
same_type(a,c);
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why this is not part of standard C, at least in the case where the types are known at compile time?

Comment: No one found it of sufficient importance to push to add it to the standard, or it entails too much extra infrastructure to be accepted, @ZachBoyd.

Comment: That makes sense--I suppose that keeping C compilers easy to implement is a valid priority.

Comment: @ZachBoyd: There's no need to have an assertion to test condition which would generate a compilation squawk if not satisfied, and I don't think anybody on the Committee imagined that anyone should care about whether an implementation with both 64-bit `long` and 64-bit `long long` mapped `int64_t` to the former or the latter in cases where a compiler wouldn't squawk.