# Have I applied the rule of strict aliasing correctly?

Tags: c, buffer, strict-aliasing

My current (simplified) buffer API looks like this:

```c
typedef struct {
    size_t offset;
    size_t size;
    uint8_t *data;
} my_buffer;

// Writes an unsigned int 8 to the buffer
bool my_buffer_write_u8(my_buffer *buffer, uint8_t value) {
    if (buffer->offset >= buffer->size) return false;

    buffer->data[buffer->offset] = value;
    ++buffer->offset;
    return true;
}
```

However, after refreshing my knowledge about the strict aliasing rule in C I'm not so sure about this use case:

```c
    char string[32];

    my_buffer buffer;
    buffer.size = sizeof(string);
    buffer.data = string; // <-- I think this violates the strict aliasing rule
    buffer.offset = 0;

    // the function calls access buffer.data which is defined to be `uint8_t *` and not `char *`
    // in other words, I'm manipulating a `char *` through a `uint8_t *`:
    // even though uint8_t is almost always unsigned char, it is nevertheless not the same as unsigned char
    my_buffer_write_u8(&buffer, 'h');
    my_buffer_write_u8(&buffer, 'e');
    my_buffer_write_u8(&buffer, 'l');
    my_buffer_write_u8(&buffer, 'l');
    my_buffer_write_u8(&buffer, 'o');
    my_buffer_write_u8(&buffer, '\0');
```

I think I should be using `void *` in the buffer struct and use a `(char *)` cast to access the underlying data:

```c
typedef struct {
    size_t offset;
    size_t size;
    void *data;
} my_buffer;

// Writes an unsigned int 8 to the buffer
bool my_buffer_write_u8(my_buffer *buffer, uint8_t value) {
    if (buffer->offset >= buffer->size) return false;

    unsigned char *data = (unsigned char *)buffer->data;

    data[buffer->offset] = value;
    ++buffer->offset;

    return true;
}
```

Because `char *`, `unsigned char *` and `signed char *` are always assumed to alias other datatypes.

The same cannot be said about `uint8_t *` (according to the standard that is)

If `CHAR_BIT` is `8` then this adjusted code with `(void *)` should do exactly the same as with the `uint8_t` version.

Now to the question: have I applied the rule of strict aliasing correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be UB if `uint8_t` was different from `unsigned char`.Assuming  `uint8_t` exists it is very unlikely because

- CHAR_BIT is at least 8, see [http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1p1](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1p1)
- unsigned char has no padding bits
- unsigned char is the smallest addressable unit

However, the standard does not explicitly require that `uint8_t` is the same type as `unsigned char`. Therefore it's rather implementation defined.

Consider applying solution from following thread to check it forementioned types are the same.
[How to assert two types are equal in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53840498/4989451)

It is preferable to use `char*`/`unsigned char*` for accessing the data. However, if refactoring of the code would be cumbersome then just add a check if the types `uint8_t` and `unsigned char` are the same and reject compilation if not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm aware that such a scenario is very unlikely. However, I don't want to get in the habit of writing code that has technically undefined behaviour. It's very hard to make assumptions in C. I guess the latter code (with char) is fine then?

Comment: @marco-a, it's preferable to use `char*` however if refactoring is cumbersome you can just add an assertions that `uint8_t` and `unsigned char` are the same

Comment: Awesome. I'll take the time to refactor my code.

Comment: @marco-a: Just about every non-trivial program for a freestanding implementation relies upon behaviors that will generally be defined identically by nearly all freestanding implementations for a given platform, but upon which the Standard imposes no requirements.  The only people who should care about things that are "technically" UB are those who want to bend over backward to accommodate Gratuitously Clever Compilers or Crazy Language-Abusing Nonsense Generators who interpret the phrase "non-portable or erroneous" as "non-portable, and therefore erroneous".