# Trying to pass a value to a function that takes a pointer as argument

Tags: c, function, pointers

Ive been searching far and wide for the answer but havent been able to come op with a viable solution. As you can see in my code beneath, I'am trying to pass the value of choice into get_user_input(char *input). I think this is what i want to do because i need the function scanf to be called inside get_user_input(char *input).

I'am fairly new to programming and have alot of trouble trying to understand pointers and references

I hope someone could help me out!

**The get_user_input(char *input) function***

```
void get_user_input(char *input) {
     *input = '\0' ;


    scanf(" %c", input);
}
```

**Trying to call scanf() from the function get_user_input(char *input)***

```
void manual_read_sensors(void) {
    while (1) {
        // Ask the user for which sensor to read.
        printf("Which sensor do you want to read?\n"
               "(i)ntensity\n"
               "(a)ngle\n"
               "(t)ime\n"
               "(s)unscreen\n"
               "(q)uit\n"
               "Enter choice: ");
        void choice = get_user_input(); <----- Trying to call 

        // Return to the main menu again.
        if (choice == 'q')
            break;
```

Comment: void is not a type, you need to pass a char pointer to the function and now you are not passing anything. And the function does not return anything.Your compiler should have pointed all these errors out to you.

Comment: What you want to do is change choice to char and pass a pointer to it as an argument to get_user_info.

Comment: The code doesn't work because `void choice` doesn't make sense. You can't program by trial and error. Study the basics of variables, then the basics of functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your `get_user_input` function accepts a `char *` and doesn't return anything, but you are not passing anything - You should pass the address of `choice` like: `get_user_input(&choice);`. If you  pass the address of `choice`, the `get_user_input` function will be able to write data to it.

Second, `void choice` is not a valid declaration. Although you can declare a `void *choice`. In this case, you should declare `choice` as a `char`: `char choice;`.

Third, `get_user_input` does not return anything and you should not try to assign the result of the function to a variable.

Fourth, `*input = '\0' ;` does not achieve anything as in the next step, you overwrite `input` with `scanf`.

`get_user_input` should look like this:

```
void get_user_input(char *input) {
     scanf(" %c", input);
}
```

`manual_read_sensors` should look like:

```
void manual_read_sensors(void) {
    char choice;
    while (1) {
        // Ask the user for which sensor to read.
        printf("Which sensor do you want to read?\n"
               "(i)ntensity\n"
               "(a)ngle\n"
               "(t)ime\n"
               "(s)unscreen\n"
               "(q)uit\n"
               "Enter choice: ");
        
        get_user_input(&choice); 

        // Return to the main menu again.
        if (choice == 'q')
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared that **get_user_input()** function takes a char reference as its argument. But when this function was called from **manual_read_sensors()** function, there was no reference passed to get_user_input() function.

**choice** variable cannot be declared as type void because this is not allowed in C/C++ language ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487689/is-void-a-data-type-in-c)).
Rather try declaring,

```
char choice;
```

Since **get_user_input()** function is declared as having **void** as return type, it cannot return any value to other function and hence, a variable cannot be assigned a value like so,

```
char choice = get_user_input(); //error
```

Since **get_user_input()** does not return any value, we need to use pointer variable for manipulating **choice** variable. But the pointer variable also requires the address of the variable to point to, that's why we need to pass the reference (or address) of **choice** variable to **get_user_input()** function. Like so,

```
get_user_input(&choice);
```